# Match a number only in a certain range

Tags: regex

I want to match a 3-digit number only from a webpage.

So for example if webpage has number `1 599-+` (white space between `1` and `5` and `-+` signs after).  I **only** want to capture/match numbers between `0` and `599-+` and nothing else.

My regex is: `regex(?:^|(?:[^\d\s]\s*))([0-5]\d\d-+)` but this one also matches `"i 1599-+"`

or `regex(\^[0-5]?[0-9]?[0-9]-+$)`  doesnt work either...

Comment: What regex flavour and language/tool are you using ? Can you show the relevant code ?

Comment: You're missing word boundary or anchors as the case may be.

Comment: @devnull I don't think it's as simple as that, if he's doing a search

Comment: **Regular expressions are for matching patterns, not checking numeric values.** Find a likely string with the regex, then check its numeric value in whatever your host language is (PHP, whatever).

Comment: I only want it to match a 3-digit number (between 0-599 isn't necessary).

Comment: Still no good answer on my question. I put all examples now on MATCH and NO MATCH: MATCH: "400-+", "200-+", "588-+" NO MATCH: "1 400-+", "o 100-+", "y 800-+", "500", "i 700-+"

Answer (score 3):

A solution would be to use this regular expression with a non capturing group matching either the start of the string or something that's not a digit (with a little more verbosity due to space handling) :

```
(?:^|(?:[^\d\s]\s*))([0-5]\d\d)
```

Examples (in javascript as you didn't specify a language) :

```
"1 599".match(/(?:^|(?:[^\d\s]\s*))([0-5]\d\d)/) => null
"a sentence with 1 599 inside".match(/(?:^|(?:[^\d\s]\s*))([0-5]\d\d)/) => null
"another with 599".match(/(?:^|(?:[^\d\s]\s*))([0-5]\d\d)/) => ["h 599", "599"]
"599 at the start".match(/(?:^|(?:[^\d\s]\s*))([0-5]\d\d)/) => ["599", "599"]
```

(desired group is at index 1)

Comment: Thanks. If webpage has "1 599-+", how can I get a match on 0-599-+" ? I tested (?:^|(?:[^\d\s]\s*))([0-5]-+\d\d) but didnt work out...

Comment: You mean the two chars "-" and "+" ? Where would this "0" come from ?

Comment: Wild guess : are you looking for `(?:^|(?:[^1-9\s]\s*))([0-5]\d\d-?\+?)` ?

Comment: (?:^|(?:[^0-9\s]\s*))([0-7]\d\d-?\+?) works but why not working as this: regex(?:^|(?:[^0-9\s]\s*))([0-7]\d\d:?\-?)    ???

Comment: sorry my mistake. (?:^|(?:[^\d\s]\s*))([0-5]\d\d-+) does the job but it matches also "i 500-+" So I want it to only match "500-+"

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough. You should 1) put some code in your question 2) give a list of test cases. Right now it looks like you just want `^[0-5]\d\d-?\+?$`.

Comment: ok. my code: regex(?:^|(?:[^\d\s]\s*))([0-5]\d\d-+) It will match "500-+" and not match "1 500-+". So far, so good. But it will also match "i 500-+". So I dont want it to match any digit or character before, just only the pure format "500-+" (numbers up to 500). I hope I put the question more nailed now... :-)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is needed for you.Try it, if it is not fulfilling.Write a little more description.

```
/^[0-5]?[0-9]?[0-9]$/.test("599");
```

Comment: BINGO ! Perfect I got it now!

Comment: @user3214294: Now you do :)

Comment: sorry could you please check question again on top. I have edited it. The solution you provided regex(/^[0-5]?[0-9]?[0-9]$/) does also match "i 599" and I dont want it to match the "i" sign or anything before so to say. Please help

Answer (score 0):

From the above I understood and developed this, I think this is what you needed.

```
/^[0-5]?[0-9]?[0-9][\+|-]?$/.test("599");
```

In the above regex I made + - as optional and it'll check for presence of any one sign.
If you want in the order of -+ then try this
`/^[0-5]?[0-9]?[0-9][\-][\+]$/.test("99-+");` .
Okay @user3214294

Comment: I will try immediately. I post the result soon

Comment: Tried: ([0-5]?[0-9]?[0-9][\-][\+]$) Matches: 500-+, "200-+" in "i 200-+". Still not any solution for me... :-(

Comment: I put some examples here what to MATCH and NOT MATCH: MATCH: "400-+", "200-+", "588-+" NO MATCH: "1 400-+", "o 100-+", "y 800-+", "500", "i 700-+"

Comment: Alright,
I want to know in which lang you are running above regex, I'm running that in javascript and getting the result as you asked.

Comment: Hi its Basic scripting language